# Combining the select clause in query function with Indirect function. - Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

So basically I need a dynamic select statement which changes references when dragged across rows or columns.

Example of what I need.
=sum(query('Sheet1'!$A$1:$F$621, Indirect("Select"&$F&"Where A='ABC' AND B="&"Sheet2!"&$A1)))/20

Sample Sheet 1 (Data Sheet)..--Since I am not allowed to use images till i reach rep 10 lol :)

1. Column 1 - Sales Sites (ABC, DEF, GHI.....)
2. Column 2 - Sales Roles (SM, ASM, SE.....)
3. Column 3 - Sales in Month Jan
4. Column 4 - Sales in Month Feb
5. Column 5 - Sales in Month Mar

Sample Sheet 2 (Desired Output)

Description (in pivot terms):

1. Site wise (filter)
2. Role wise (Rows)
3. Month wise (Columns - Sum of Jan, Feb etc)
4. Value (Sum of Jan/20)--To get day wise sales numbers

FYI:

1. I have tried using pivots, but google spreadsheets don't allow use of calculated fields in pivots in any manner (for the /20 in the formula), hence trying to achieve the same results by formula.
2. I know a table on the basis of the pivot table could help solve this problem, but to make it more efficient I am trying to avoid using 2 tables.

Many Thanks for your help in advance, please let me know if you need additional info to understand the scenario.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?   This [ArrayFormula talk is all I can find](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/bwr5tXxite0)

Comment: Without seeing your real data, you can experiment with something like this, which allows for "dynamic" column selection: `=sum(query('Sheet1'!$A$1:$F$621,"Select "&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A2),4,TRUE), "[A-Z]+")&" Where A='ABC'")/20`